# Angular 5 - How to add a $ sign to a input filed

Tags: angular

I got a amount picker component for using to enter the amount in the input field and the slider to choose the amount.

Something like this
[image]

And the code

```
<div class="row clearfix consumer-slider">
  <div class="half-width">
    <div class="col-left row clearfix rel inlined-label flex">
      <label class=" half-width slider-label inline accent-color">{{ label }}</label>
      <mat-input-container class=" half-width inline slider-inputs">
        <input matInput name="amountRequired" [min]="minAmount"  type="text"  [max]="maxAmount" placeholder=""  (change)="changeAmountValue()" [(ngModel)]="amount">
      </mat-input-container>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="half-width">
    <div class="col-right">
      <div class="row clearfix rel">
        <!-- range slider for amount required -->
        <mat-slider class="full-width" [min]="minAmount" [max]="maxAmount" step="{{step}}" [(ngModel)]="amount" thumbLabel (change)="updateAmountValue($event)"></mat-slider>

        <p class="min-amount small">{{minAmount | customCurrency}}</p>
        <p class="max-amount small">{{maxAmount | customCurrency}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The question I want to ask is how to add a $ sign just in front of the number.

I tried to add the `<span matPrefix>$ &nbsp;</span>`, but the $ sign is in the beginning of the input filed, which is not what I want.

[image]

What I am trying to achieve is the input filed should display the number with a $ sign in front, and the slider also have the control to change the number.

My code is working fine without the $ sign.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: on which tag are you trying to add $ sign? On  <input matInput name="amountRequired"....> or  <p class="min-amount s.....

Answer (score 0):

The standard way of representing your value in currency is to use the `currency` pipe like `<span>{{myValue | currency }} </span>`

Comment: Have you also considered using font awesome?

Comment: I don know how this is going to help me by using font awesome?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more an HTML CSS question. Since you are on an input field, it unfortunately does not register pseudo elements like ::before or after which would have made this a breeze. Just like inputs with password reveals buttons or the eye icon, you will need a wrapper and two elements:

```html
<div class="input-wrapper">
  <span class="input-currency">$</span>
 <input type="number" name="amount" />
</div>
```

And for your CSS

```
.input-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
.input-currency {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: calc(100% - 1.35em);
  line-height: 1em;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.input-wrapper > input {
  padding-left: 16px;
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

This will essentially achieve what you are looking for. Alignment is for another topic but what is important is that your wrapper has a position relative, the currency or span has a position absolute and the left padding on your input is a little greater than the left position of your span.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

If the currency sign is fixed, i.e. no need to be local and no need to be formatted, then this will always work:

```
   <p class="min-amount small">${{minAmount}}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong bound. You need banana-in-box binding [(ngModel)]="serial" instead of [ngModel]="serial"

() in the binding will update serial model everytime when the input will be changes. From input into model

Single [] will just bind the data of serial if it will be changed by code manually. This will cause to one-way binding - from model into input.

As you guess - together [()] they will make two-way binding